# JavaScript Function reload automatically

Tags: javascript, html

the problem here is i don't need input field required when i remove required the table still empty and another problem when i enter (not valid character)
also the table data will be deleted

i need the input field not required and when click add it adds a new row

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput")
    myTable = document.getElementById("myTable")
    i = 1
    num = 1
    tabledata = myTable.innerHTML;


    function arr() {
        
                if(myInput.value!=""){
        
                if(/^[a-z]+$/i.test(myInput.value)){
        
                if (num % 2 == 0) {
                    myTable.innerHTML = myTable.innerHTML + '<tr style="background:#ff8000"><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + myInput.value + "</td></tr>";
                    myInput.value = "";
                    i++;
                } else {
                    myTable.innerHTML = myTable.innerHTML + '<tr style="background:#ffb366"><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + myInput.value + "</td></tr>";
                    myInput.value = "";
                    i++;
                }
                num++;
            }
         else {
              alert("Please Enter A Valid Charceter"); 
        
          }
         }else{
         alert("This Field Is Reqiured Please Enter Your Name") 
         }}; 

function res() {
    myTable.innerHTML = "<tr> <th>Id</th> <th>Name</th> </tr>";
    i = 1;
    num = 1;
}
```

```html
   <h1>Enter Your Name</h1>
        <form>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" required/>
        <button onclick="arr()">Add</button>
        </form>
        <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>     
        </tr>
        </table>
        <button onclick ="res()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: unclear what you want to do. edit your question

Comment: Ortography and punctuation would help to improve readability.

Comment: Is your keyboard broken? Weird capitalization and lack of punctuation is making it hard to understand.

Comment: Okay: 1) An error bubble shows up upon adding a new value even though the field wasn't empty. 2) If an invalid character is entered, the entire table disappears.

Comment: guys when i click button while i remove required from input nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't fully understand what you need, but I see here a little bit flaw:
When you click the "Add" button, the form is submitting, so you need to break this.

Try it:

```
<style>
    #myTable tr {
        background: #FF8000
    }

    #myTable tr:nth-child(odd){
        background: #FFB366
    }
</style>

<h1>Enter Your Name</h1>

<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" required />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable"></tbody>
</table>

<button id="myButton">Reset</button>

<script>
    (function(){
        "use strict";

        var
            form  = document.getElementById("myForm"),
            input = document.getElementById("myInput"),
            table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
            reset = document.getElementById("myButton");


        form.addEventListener("submit", add, true);
        function add(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            if( /^[a-z]+$/i.test(myInput.value) )
                table.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + (table.children.length + 1) + '</td><td>' + input.value + '</td></tr>';


            return input.value = '';
        }

        function reset(){
            table.innerHTML = '';
        }
    })()
</script>
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` should fix both issues.

Comment: @LGT, so he is mean that when clicking the button, a "Required" hint shows and if enter incorrectly chars, the whole table disappears?

Just, my English is bad and I think I can not understand something...

Comment: @TurarAbu yes that is what i mean but i need to remove required from input field when i remove it the button doesn't add anything

Comment: @TurarAbu Thanks a lot it worked but what did you do??

Comment: @J.Roger When you click "Add" button the form is submitting. So, when regex test is ok script clear the input and form can't submit because input has a "required" attribute. But, when regex test returns false, the script just show alert and do nothing.

For fix use preventDefault(); anyway
Function says - don't submit the form and page not updating